# gcloud app deploy stuck at Updating service [default]...failed. Application startup error ...Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, .net-core, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to deploy .net core app on google app engine. Remote build output gets stuck at

`Updating service [default]...failed. ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Timed out when starting VMs. It's possible that the application code is unhealthy. (0/2 ready, 2 still deploying).` 
after 5 mins or so. This is the first time deployment.

While checking in the logs found one line stated as

`Application startup error ...Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from ...link`.

Earlier Dockerfile had the following configuration

`FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1.0-runtime
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "actualdllname.dll"]`.

Based on this changed Dockerfile to add following additional lines:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install .NET Core
ENV DOTNET_VERSION 1.1.0
ENV DOTNET_DOWNLOAD_URL https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release/1.1.0/Binaries/$DOTNET_VERSION/dotnet-debian-x64.$DOTNET_VERSION.tar.gz

RUN curl -SL $DOTNET_DOWNLOAD_URL --output dotnet.tar.gz \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet \
    && tar -zxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet \
    && rm dotnet.tar.gz \
    && ln -sfn /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet
```

This script didn't give any error during `gcloud app deploy`.

Still not able to resolve error.

Comment: The service updating failing with that error suggests the application cannot start within the container.  If you'd like to save yourself some trouble shooting time, I'd suggest using `--verbosity debug` when using `gcloud app deploy`.  Does your ASP.NET docker container properly deploy and run on your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Easy deployment steps are provided in the "Deploy an ASP.NET Core app to App Engine" [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-aspnetcore/#0). It includes a recommended procedure for installing the dotnet SDK.